# Add time to datetime object with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp, strtotime

I have an datetime object and I try to add 2 days to that object using `strtotime` function (this is optional, I am open to any working solution).

When I add 2 days to my object I am getting a timestamp as a result:

```
$new_datetime = strtotime('+2 days' . date_format($datetime, 'd/m/Y h:i A'));
```

It would not be a problem but I want to loop through number of modified datetime objects with following code:

```
$datetimeArray[] = $datetime;
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++){
    $datetimeArray[] = strtotime('+' . $interval . " " . $timeUnit .
                       date_format($datetimeArray[$i], 'd/m/Y h:i A'));
}
```

Because `strtotime` gives me a timestamp on the second spin of the loop I will get an error message:
`date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, integer given`

How can I modify my code to either have a array of `datetime` objects or `timestamps`?

Comment: Timestamps are easy to use, since they represent the number of seconds since 1 January 1970. If you want to add +2 days to a timestamp, you add 2*24*60*60 seconds to that timestamp!

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I have added a datetime object before the loop. I thought it is obvious but I guess you did not 1.Engage brain before starting to answer

Comment: Back at ya buddy! We are **not clairvoyant** we see only what you show us **and only what you show us**

Comment: Now show us what is in `$times`

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the dot in this line to a comma as it is a comma that seperates the parameters in a `strtotime()` function.

From

```
$datetimeArray[] = strtotime('+' . $interval . ' ' . $timeUnit .
                   date_format($datetimeArray[$i], 'd/m/Y h:i A'));
```

To

```
$datetimeArray[] = strtotime('+' . $interval . ' ' . $timeUnit ,
                   date_format($datetimeArray[$i], 'd/m/Y h:i A'));
```

But unless `$times = 1` the second time through your for loop there will be nothing to process and it will probably crash.

Comment: when I changed the dot to comma I got follwoing error: `A non well formed numeric value encountered`